# Can i get person account fields in custom report type

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

In the report type considerations document available [here](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/reports_report_type_guidelines.htm),  that Person account fields cannot be added to custom report type.

Are these fields stored in the contact table?  Can i use the add fields via contact lookup instead and get these fields in a report type?

Please suggest any other workarounds you might have used.

Answer (score 4):

We use Person Accounts (PA) extensively and I have their fields in multiple Custom Report Types (CRT). You just need to add them via lookup.

When you click `Add fields related via lookup`, `Person Account` and `Person Contact` are both options let you select the PA fields, such as email and mailing address (see attached screenshot.)

[image]